# Parallel Pytest Fixtures Processing

Tags: python-3.x, docker, parallel-processing, pytest, fixtures

I am using PyTest, and suppose I have a test function named `test_func`, which has two arguments named `docker_mysql` and `docker_clickhouse`, which are functions-fixtures in PyTest terminology. In this two functions I am pulling docker image and start it. Due to mechanism of fixtures, `test_func` calls fixtures step by step, so, the second docker container runs only after the first starts.

So, the question is: how to parallelize process of pulling docker containers to save time, because waiting for many docker containers in queue would be so annoying in the nearest future.

Personally, I've tried [pytest-xdist](https://medium.com/@kozyreva.hanna/pytest-xdist-with-session-scoped-fixture-b9884bd7bb29) but in CI-CD I didn't mention any changes in velocity. Also, I tried to make fixture that would do a thread using `from threading import Thread`, but I crashed.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this using Thread and it worked.

```
from datetime import datetime
from queue import Queue
from threading import Thread
import time

import pytest


def _pull_and_start_docker_mysql():
    print(datetime.now(), "Start downloading docker_mysql")
    time.sleep(5)  # Simulate download
    print(datetime.now(), "Finished downloading docker_mysql")
    return "MySQL"

def _pull_and_start_docker_clickhouse():
    print(datetime.now(), "Start downloading docker_clickhouse")
    time.sleep(8)  # Simulate download
    print(datetime.now(), "Finished downloading docker_clickhouse")
    return "Clickhouse"


@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def docker():
    results = Queue()  # Needed to store the results of the threads
    p1 = Thread(target=lambda: results.put(("docker_mysql", _pull_and_start_docker_mysql())))  # To identify the result, we put an identifier name "docker_mysql"
    p2 = Thread(target=lambda: results.put(("docker_clickhouse", _pull_and_start_docker_clickhouse())))  # To identify the result, we put an identifier name "docker_clickhouse"
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
    return [results.get() for _ in range(results.qsize())]


def test_func(docker):
    print("Inside test_func", docker)
    assert True


def test_func2(docker):
    print("Inside test_func2", docker)
    assert True
```

```
$ pytest -rP
=========================================================================================== test session starts ===========================================================================================
collected 2 items                                                                                                                                                                                         

test_docker.py ..                                                                                                                                                                                    [100%]

================================================================================================= PASSES ==================================================================================================
________________________________________________________________________________________________ test_func ________________________________________________________________________________________________
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ Captured stdout setup ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2021-08-17 01:26:21.113417 Start downloading docker_mysql
2021-08-17 01:26:21.113675 Start downloading docker_clickhouse
2021-08-17 01:26:26.125081 Finished downloading docker_mysql
2021-08-17 01:26:29.122935 Finished downloading docker_clickhouse
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ Captured stdout call -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Inside test_func [('docker_mysql', 'MySQL'), ('docker_clickhouse', 'Clickhouse')]
_______________________________________________________________________________________________ test_func2 ________________________________________________________________________________________________
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ Captured stdout call -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Inside test_func2 [('docker_mysql', 'MySQL'), ('docker_clickhouse', 'Clickhouse')]
============================================================================================ 2 passed in 8.04s ============================================================================================
```

Some notes:

1. As visible in the logs, both the processes for `docker_mysql` and `docker_clickhouse` started at the same time 01:26:21 and ended after the sleep of 5 and 8 seconds respectively (to simulate different execution times).
2. I used `"session"` scope as documented [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html#fixture-scopes) so that it doesn't re-execute the fixture for every test, as visible in the logs after running both `test_func` and `test_func2`. Check if this is also applicable to your scenario.
3. Currently, the format of the fixture's response is a list of <Identifier, Result> e.g. `[('docker_mysql', 'MySQL'), ...]`. You may want to reformat this e.g. to dict based on your use case.